# Monkeytalk : I cannot run javascript

Tags: ios-ui-automation

I am trying to automate my IOS app using monekytalk but here is the issue :

In Monekytalk we can export mt(monkeytalk script) to JS (java script) and edit it

1stly : i dont get that run tool bar on top when js is focused
But when i focus on mt file that run tool bar comes
Even if i run , it runs it's mt script files and not Run js

I have gone through may pdf and every where it is written that if js file is there it by default runs the js file but actually it does not happen.

Can some one please help me in this i am doing it for IOS

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

mt file will be must, and you can export mt file to js file and then changes in js file with all programming logics and then call that js file inside mt file...example
login.mt file will have command Script login.js Run. and you can get run till bar only when mt file is focused however in this way you are running you javascript code from your mt file...hope it would help.

Answer (score 0):

mt file is must to run the test, you can create a js file and include it in the mt file JavaScript tab using the following

load("myscript.js");

and calling the methods.